# How to change data in fire base in offline mode android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I am working on chat module in my project. For this module I am using Firebase.

In this module I have to display user's online and offline status. The offline and online status is working in all scenarios, like when he close the application, logout application etc.

But the problem is when user A is chatting with user B, if unfortunately user B net connection got disconnected or in airplane mode, that time I cannot able to update the offline status in firebase. Because of this user A still sees user B as Online

Please find my code below along with my Firebase structure:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            //System.out.println("connected");
            Map<String, Object> typingKey = new HashMap<>();
            typingKey.put("status", "online");
            mDatabaseReference.child(FirebaseConstants.USERS).child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(FirebaseConstants.PROFILE).updateChildren(typingKey);
            //Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
             //here if try update data it is getting updated 
            //Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "no connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "cancel connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

[image: fire]

Comment: What you're describing is a presence system, and can be implemented as shown in the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample. You've implemented the initial part of it, but are missing the `onDisconnect` handlers. Implementing it exactly/completly as shown in the documentation will get you much closer to your goal.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used ondiconnect method to update data the problem is when i went to offline it is not updating values but when i came back to online that time it is updating the values which i want to update when i went to offline

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your code and call it before sender sending the message.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

and add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: This code will detect my network status but I want like when user A is chatting with User B if B got disconnected user A need to know user B has been disconnected

Comment: I'm assuming that this app would be installed in both A and B then it would detect the network status of the user which maybe A or B and update in the firebase according to their connectivity. Then the other person would know whether if the receiver is online or oflline.

Comment: what you said is correct that what I doing now the question is if user has disconnected from network that time how can i update status in fire base

Comment: Yess. If the user is disconnected then you can trigger onDisconnect()  to update the status of the user. You can refer to this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect

Comment: yes onDisconnect() will trigger but i tried to update data from that but it is not getting updated